# The `WToolkit` thinks I'm on Windows Vista when I'm actually running Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10

Java's `WToolkit` seems to think my computer is running on Windows Vista even though I'm running on Windows 10, as is shown by the system properties. Why is it also using native 32-bit graphic-rendering classes?

```
[16:57:51] [] main > INFO: Operating System: Windows 10 (10.0) amd64
[16:57:51] [sun.awt.windows.WToolkit] main > FINE: Win version: 0x2800000a = 671088650 (Windows Vista)
[16:57:51] [sun.awt.multiscreen.SunDisplayChanger] main > FINER: Adding listener: sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig@58372a00[dev=Win32GraphicsDevice[screen=0],pixfmt=0]
```

I've also been having a similar problem where `SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait` just freezes, whether I use a lamba expression, anonymous class or method reference inside a `static` body (called at `clinit` phase for the class). That `static` body is logging under the `main` thread, so calling it from the EDT can't be the problem.

Comment: Presumably because the kernel version for Windows 10 may in some cases still be a `6.x` derivative - though apparently that's supposed to have changed (http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/11/why-windows-10-isnt-version-6-any-more-and-why-it-will-probably-work/), it looks like `WToolkit` interprets any `6.x` version as Vista (which is where that kernel started).

Comment: Yet the `os.arch` system property is `10.0`, which can definitely not be interpreted as `6.x`